# Анонимные типы в c# и их особенности?

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Начал изучать анонимные типы в C#.
Автор приводит пример синтаксиса анонимного типа `var instance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27 };` и предлагает последовательно — шаг за шагом добавить на эту строку дополнительные элементы синтаксиса, чтобы данная строк стала более узнаваемая "читаемая" для нас (напоминаю: автор это делает т.к пример и весь курс — учебный) т.е. превратив выше приведенную строку в

```
var instance = new MyClass() { Name = "Alex", Age = 27 };
```

говоря, что мы добавили имя конструктора по умолчанию и круглые скобки для приема аргументов конструктора, и тут же демонстрируеь, что добавляя это — студия предлагает сгенерировать нам свойства для `Age` и для `Name` в классе `MyClass`(класс он создал сам — опять же для примера, но сказал, что в анонимных типах при генерации свойств класс также создаётся автоматически).
В классе сгенерировались автореализуемые свойства
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но автор сказал, что они должны быть только для чтения, т.е. в (ну в данном случае посто нужно убрать `set` — ведь студия генерировала свойства как для обычных полей класса когда мы дописала имя конструктора по умолчаню после ключевого слова `new`).
И это подводит меня к вопросу №3 (вопросы №1 и №2 представлены ниже). Если автогенерируемые, автореализуемые свойства в также автоматически созданном классе (назовем его `MyClass`) только для чтения, то каким образом в блоке инициализатора на строке `var instance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27 };` мы вообще можем присваивать этим полям значения?
Вот скриншот первого примера, в котором меня интересует комментарий, в котором у меня и возникают все эти вопросы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос №1: т.е. компилятор каждый раз создает новое имя для анонимного типа, который в свою очередь является ссылочным типом?

Вопрос №2: т.е. приложение не может обращаться ссылке (т.к. тип ссылочный) к 
новому имени созданному компилятором.

Вопрос №3 представлен вначале.

Comment: второй вопрос совсем не понятен

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что мне непонятно, почему сгенерированные имена для анонимных типов недоступны для приложения?

Comment: Извиняюсь за вопрос №2 - там был косяк  - исправил. теперь звучит так Вопрос №2 т.е приложение не может обращаться ссылке(т.к тип ссылочный) к 
новому имени созданному компилятором?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Да, так задумано. Компилятор создаёт имя наподобие `<>f__AnonymousType0`, которое невозможно использовать из C#. К нему невозможно получить доступ просто так, потому что такие имена нельзя использовать в C#. Но вы легко можете увидеть это имя при помощи рефлексии:

   ```
   class Program
   {
       public static void Main()
       {
           var o = new { x = 5, y = 8 };
           foreach (var t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
               Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
       }
   }
   ```

   выдаёт

   > <>f__AnonymousType0`2
   >   Program
   >   Settings

   (`` `2 `` означает, что класс на самом деле является generic-классом по причинам, указанным [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/12/20/why-are-anonymous-types-generic/))
2. Программа вполне может обращаться по ссылке к значениям этого типа. Просто она не может получить *имя* типа, чтобы, например, объявить тип возвращаемого значения. Обращение на чтение работает:

   ```
   var o = new { x = 5, y = 8 }; // var необходим, т. к. мы не можем назвать имя
   Console.WriteLine(o.x); // обращение по ссылке
   ```
3. Нет, присваивать свойствам анонимного типа нельзя. Они создаются вовсе без сеттера. На самом деле вот такой код:

   ```
   var o = new { x = 5, y = 8 };
   ```

   порождает (примерно) следующий класс:

   ```
   [DebuggerDisplay("{ x = {x}, y = {y} }", Type = "<Anonymous Type>")]
   public sealed class Anonymous<TX, TY>
   {
       private readonly TX field_x;
       private readonly TY field_y;

       public TX x { get { return field_x; } }
       public TY y { get { return field_y; } }

       [DebuggerHidden]
       public Anonymous(PX x, PY y)
       {
           field_x = x;
           field_y = y;
       }

       public override bool Equals(object value) { /* тут имплементация */ }
       public override int GetHashCode() { /* тут имплементация */ }
       public override string ToString() { /* тут имплементация */ }
   }
   ```

   а ваш вызов превращается компилятором в следующее:

   ```
   Anomymous<int, int> o = new Anonymous<int, int>(5, 8);
   ```

   Вы видите, что на самом деле присвоения свойствам нету, а есть просто вызов конструктора. Поэтому в дальнейшем запись в эти же свойства невозможна.

Comment: _К нему невозможно получить доступ просто так, потому что такие имена нельзя использовать в C#_ - даже проще, потому что это имя **неизвестно** до момента компиляции.

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, даже если мы скомпилируем этот модуль, узнаем после этого имя, и теперь попробуем воспользоваться им из _другого_ модуля, это не покатит.

Comment: не совсем понял, что ты имеешь ввиду :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, имя не известно до момента компиляции модуля, в котором оно определено, это да. Но после компиляции оно же известно? Так что теоретически _другой_ модуль мог бы им воспользоваться, если скомпилировать этот другой модуль потом.

Comment: А разве через рефлексию он не может им воспользоваться? :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Может, конечно. Но рефлексия — это внеязыковое средство. :)

Comment: @VladD а я бы всё-таки рефлексию упомянул бы в ответе. Мне кажется новичкам (а это всё-таки вопрос скорей новичка) было бы полезно знать о том, что можно рефлексией менять неизменяемые типы.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Хм, может лучше новичкам это не рассказывать до поры до времени? А то начнут писать ужасную архитектуру, надеясь на рефлексию или там unsafe-код для модификации того, что модифицировать нельзя.