# Модификация анонимного типа в рантайме

Tags: c#

В хелпер asp.net я передаю переменную htmlAttributes вида:

```
new { @class = "btn btn-default", title = "classic view" };
```

При этом внутри хелпера мне иногда нужно добавить css класс active при выполнении некоторого условия:

```
new { @class = "btn btn-default active", title = "classic view" };
```

Как это сделать проще всего?

Сам я попробовал полезть через рефлексию

```
foreach (var i in htmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.Write(i.GetValue(a));
}
```

, но вспомнил, что анонимные типы - только для чтения, они вообще [без setter'ов создаются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/601889/213987).

Можно ли создать копию, с немного другими значениями?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут все зависит от того что потребитель будет делать с этим объектом. Для передачи в хелперы Razor проще всего преобразовать объект в RouteValueDictionary и дальше использовать другую перегрузку:

```
var dict = new RouteValueDictionary(obj);
dict["class"] += " active";
```

Также можно "обмануть" потребителя передав ему объект реализующий [`ICustomTypeDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) - многие потребители, и Razor в их числе, используют именно ComponentModel вместо рефлексии для получения свойств объекта.

Если же объект предполагается передавать в интерпретируемые языки использующие  DLR - то можно использовать [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();
foreach (var pair in new RouteValueDictionary(obj))
    dict.Add(pair);

dynamic foo = dict;
foo.@class += " active";
```

Ну а если требуется точное совпадение типа - ничего не поделать, придется использовать [вариант Андрея](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847680/178779) и надеяться что разработчики компилятора не поменяют особенности реализации...

Answer (score 1):

Просто создадим новый объект через рефлексию, передавая массив значений в конструктор:

```
static object CreateModified(object obj, string propName, object newValue)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var props = type.GetProperties();
    var values = props.Select(p => p.Name == propName ? newValue : p.GetValue(obj)).ToArray();
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type, values);
}
```

Решение довольно хрупкое, полагается на то, что в текущей реализации компилятора свойства в анонимном классе создаются в том же порядке, что и параметры его конструктора.

Используем:

```
var a = new { @class = "btn btn-default", title = "classic view" };
Console.WriteLine(a);
var b = CreateModified(a, "class", a.@class + " active");
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Вроде работает, но делать я так бы не стал.

Comment: Ну, по крайней мере создать всё-таки можно. Я-то уже нашёл обходной путь, меня сама проблематика заинтересовала.

Comment: Можно, есть конструктор, который можно вызвать, есть свойства, которые можно прочитать.